# How to disable `Alt sends Escape` in Konsole?

Tags: neovim, konsole

I am using [copilot.lua](https://github.com/zbirenbaum/copilot.lua) in which `<M-[>` and `<M-]>` are mapped to `prev` and `next`. In Linux, `M` is `Alt`.

However, when I type `<M-]>` in *insert mode*, it will be mapped to `Esc` (in *normal mode*), and then `]`. So it seems that **Alt sends Escape** in `konsole`. How can I disable such mapping?

I also checked the keyboard settings in the current profile, but none of them is related with it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it in Konsole — alt is supposed to send escape, and vim understands escape to mean alt/meta. Either vim is somehow being configured improperly for your terminal, or the mapping that you think is installed isn't.

To debug the first one, go into insert mode and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. If `<M-]>` is inserted then everything is configured correctly. If you leave insert mode instead, then perhaps your `$TERM` is set incorrectly, there is a problem with your terminfo database, or you're overriding some crucial vim setting.

To debug the second one, run `:imap` and verify that a `<M-]>` mapping actually appears there. If not, then start digging into your copilot.lua config.

Comment: It turns out it is caused by the second reason, and now it works in Linux. But I have another issue: in MacOS, `M` key is Option, while `<M-]>` is also mapped to a special character `‘` in Mac. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. On Mac, it insert `‘`. Let me know if you solve it!

Comment: @chenzhongpu that's an OS-level problem, almost for sure. MacOS is re-mapping that key before your terminal or vim can ever see it. I don't use macs so I'm not qualified to answer that.